# How to include google map url in custom checkout component js file in Magento 2?

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.4.4, google-map

I created a google map popup in checkout page. I want to load the google map script url.

currently i am doing like this in my google-map-loader.js

```
define([
...
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-API-KEY&libraries=places&z=18'
], function (
.......
google
) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Ayakil_GoogleMapAddressLookup/googlemaplink',
    },
---my other codes going here
```

entire functionality is working fine with me in this way. But i want to get the API Key from modules system configuration section and load it here?

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I used checkout **ConfigProviderInterface** to achieve this task.

Created the di.xml file under Ayakil/GoogleMapAddressLookup/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="google_map_key" xsi:type="object">Ayakil\GoogleMapAddressLookup\Model\GoogleMapApiKey</item>
       </argument>
   </arguments>
```

**GoogleMapApiKey.php** file content

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\GoogleMapAddressLookup\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class GoogleMapApiKey implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
{
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function getConfig()
{
    $additionalVariables['Google_key'] = $this->scopeConfig->getValue("googlemapaddresslookup/general/googleapikey");
    return $additionalVariables;
}
}
```

In the js file i got the setup variable as below

```
**window.checkoutConfig.Google_key**

'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+window.checkoutConfig.Google_key+'&libraries=places'
```